# Add existing items to To Do list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using `Rails 4.2.5` and `ruby 2.3.3p222`

I also started programming some weeks ago, so I would like to request some advice.

I want to create a To Do list where users can add items to check later. Each user should have its own To do List.

I have Users / Articles / Announcements.

I have this in my `user model`:

```
  has_many :articles
  has_many :announcements
```

And in my Articles/Announcements:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I implemented the `acts_as_follower` for the user to follow articles/announcements that other users created and will receive a notification if there's a new comment etc.

What I want to do now is to add a specific article/announcement to a To Do list, for example to check it later.

I am thinking about creating a new model called `To_do` which belongs_to :user and "has_many articles/announcements".

Is this the right way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: sounds like those relations make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by using this Gem https://github.com/pmviva/bookmark_system.

We can create a method + a page to show the itens.

Easy to set up and works perfectly.